# How to deploy Django app with nginx on non-root url?

Tags: django, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I have some boxed solutions written on Django with docker-compose. I want to deploy it on the same server and specify different root url. But if I do it Django can't find static files, because it requests this files from root url, instead of specified url. How can I say to Django that root is another url?

I was trying different examples for deploy Django with Nginx and nothing works.

Comment: Change the `STATIC_URL` settings.

Comment: this is the way, but on redeploy it will be erased, maybe I can create volume for settings, but it is the crutch

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, I suggest you read this article..

https://testdriven.io/blog/dockerizing-django-with-postgres-gunicorn-and-nginx/